# (70007)The timeout specified has expired: mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client

Tags: php, android, apache, fastcgi

I have a Phonegap App running in android, and my backend is a php App using Yii framework.

When I try to upload 10 pics, sometimes it works well, sometimes, some pics fail to upload.

In my error_logs, I have this line :

```
[Mon Mar 03 16:59:22 2014] [warn] [client 148.240.71.124] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client
```

I don't know how to manage it. I tried to raise timeout values in : /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf

but nothing changes after restarting apache
In my apache2.conf, I have no part describing mod_fcgid. Should I add one?

Any suggestion???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need change few things in your php.ini file

1. max_execution_time = 1500; or more as per your need
2. max_input_time = 1500; or more as per your need
3. post_max_size = 500M; or more as per your need

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you are using `mod_fcgid` and the settings don't allow requests to run long enough. You will need to tinker with the values in the `fcgid.conf`. On Red Hat systems, the file is located at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf` and for Debian-like OS's it's at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf`.

Specific settings will depend on your hardware and software setup, but the following are pretty safe for a low-powered server:

```
FcgidIdleTimeout 60
FcgidProcessLifeTime 30
FcgidMaxProcesses 50
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 8
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
FcgidConnectTimeout 30
FcgidIOTimeout 45
```

Another way to go is to switch your processing to Nginx and PHP-FPM instead. If you want to go that way there are plenty of guides online.

Answer (score 0):

There are three different timeouts that must all be configured under PHP-FPM in Apache:

- Timeout and ProxyTimeout in your main Apache config
- The timeout on your  definition in the virtual host
- max_execution_time and max_input_time in php.ini

See [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/505957/89796), and if you're using SetHandler and UNIX socket for your FPM pool, see my comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it was really simple. I hade debugging to remote host enabled in apache/php and the debugger was not loaded. I disabled the remote debugger and everything started to work fine.